# Books about submarine style warfare in space

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book from the late 70's early 80's in which the ships fought like submarines.  They would bend the "surface" of space to hide in a fold, then come down to fire torpedoes, then go back into the fold to hide from the enemy.  It was a one off and not part of a series.  Does anyone know what this may have been?

Comment: *Passage at Arms* by Glen Cook is very much a submarine story in space, but the terminology used ("climbing" higher into hyperspace) doesn't match what you say about hiding in folded space.

Comment: The *anacapa drive* does exactly this in Kristine Kathryn Rusch's *Diving Universe* novellas, but that is a series and started in 2013.

Comment: Possibly 'Starhunt' by David Gerrold. While 'in warp' starships can detect other vessels also in warp, but have to revert to normal space to fire their weapons

Comment: @MartinGoldsack is this related to Gerrold's *Yesterday's Children*? That's the one I thought of, with ships dropping out of warp to fire. But I need to re-read it, I pulled it down and put it on the pile.  - Edit: via isfd I see it's the same book.